# OpenCV error :error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::cvtColor

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, numpy, computer-vision

I have read many solutions regarding including the full path of the file and have tried it out but it's not working!

This is the basic code on which I am working:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys
import os

# capture frames from a video
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('F:\KUNAL ECE\SPIG\ video.avi')
#cap = cv2.VideoCapture(sys.argv[1])
# Trained XML classifiers describes some features of some object we want to detect
car_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('F:\KUNAL ECE\SPIG\cars.xml')

# loop runs if capturing has been initialized.
while True:
    # reads frames from a video
    ret, frames = cap.read()

    # convert to gray scale of each frames
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frames, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

This is the error I am getting:-

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cv::cvtColor, file C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 9748
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\KUNAL ECE\SPIG\car.py", line 20, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frames, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:9748: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::cvtColor

warning: Error opening file (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:779)
warning: F:\KUNAL ECE\SPIG\ video.avi (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:780)
[Finished in 0.5s]
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

I think opencv is not finding/ reading the avi file you specified. Try removing the space in the string

'F:/KUNAL ECE/SPIG/video.avi'

Comment: Sir I have tried it, I am getting the same error.

Comment: Does it still say this: <code>warning: Error opening file (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:779)
warning: F:\KUNAL ECE\SPIG\ video.avi (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:780)
[Finished in 0.5s]</code>? What's the new output?

Comment: Ok, also: try using 'F:/KUNAL ECE/SPIG/video.avi'

Comment: if my answer helped, pls mark it as answer :)